# Import ASE Module on python

Tags: python, bash, module, anaconda, ase

After installing 'ase' (Atomic Simulation Module) module using pip in Python 3.7.3, Failed to import the module using python shell, although it is found in the pip list.

```
>>> import ase 
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
 import ase
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ase'
```

Comment: Are you sure you successfully installed `ase`? I just tried to replicated on my machine (python 3.7, no previously installed `ase` module) and it worked fine. Can you give us the console output of `pip3 install ase` to confirm? Or perhaps you are running `python2` instead of `python3` for you shell? On most machines `python` is an alias of `python2`, and you have to explicitly enter `python3` to use 3.7.

Comment: I get this..pip3 install ase
Requirement already satisfied: ase in ./miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (3.19.1)

Comment: Can you paste the output of `pip3 show ase`? Also, you might see more comprehensive errors if you run the interpreter with the verbose flag, `python3 -v -c "import ase" 2> output.log`

Comment: It is working now just fine after uninstall anaconda which I think was causing a complication in python path. :)